# RandomForestRegressor.predict() is predicting the same result always

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I have this `df` (its an example) in a forecast context:

```
df_example
X      Y
0    65000
1    67000
2    69000
3    65000
4    68000
5    65000
6    78000
7    80000
8    73000
9    75000
10   79000
.   
.
.
51  78000
```

And also I have this code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

regr = RandomForestRegressor(max_depht=8, random_state=0, n_estimators=500, criterion='squared_error', min_samples_split=3, oob_score=True)

X=df_example['X'].values.reshape(-1,1)
y=df_example['Y'].values.reshape(-1,1)

regr.fit(X,y)

Y_pred=regr.predict(X)

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
from sklearn.metrics import explained_variance_score
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

print('MSE regr', mean_squared_error(Y, Y_pred))
print('r2 regr', r2_score(Y, Y_pred))
print('variance regr', 100-100*(explained_variance_score(Y, Y_pred)), '%')
```

outputs:

```
MSE: regr: 1215189.74
r2 regr: 0.933
variance regr: 6.65%
```

When I want to predict the 51 value I get this:

```
pred_list=[51]
a= np.array(pred_list)
a=np.expand_dims(a,0)
pred=regr.predict(a)

print('pred value is:', pred)
```

output:

```
76562.67
```

This value it's ok, but the next value, `52` its exactly the same, and the same for `53,54` and also `100`

```
pred_list=[100]
a= np.array(pred_list)
a=np.expand_dims(a,0)
pred=regr.predict(a)

print('pred value is:', pred)
```

output:

```
76562.67
```

I also tried using this:

```
X_train=X[0:44]
X_test=X[44:]
y_train=y[0:44]
```

and using:

```
regr.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

but its the same results as above.

Why this happen and how can I get the new predictions?

Answer (score 0):

The predictions you are getting, equal the prediction for the largest X. The regressor will not be able to extrapolate beyond this value. Try a different regressor.